# Using wxPython's FloatCanvas widget, is there a way to get the ControlDown information of the event?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am wondering if I can get the keyboard modifiers' status on EVT_FC_LEFT_UP events fired from a FloatCanvas.

I would prefer to do it without writing callbacks myself for keyUp and keyDown. I can't see a better method of grabbing the control status, than having a class member keep track of the modifier states over the whole window.

Is it possible to grab the state of the control key inside of the EVT_FC_LEFT_UP callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no `isKeyDown` type method in wxPython (afaik)

the only way I can see you getting this is

```
control_pressed = False
.....
self.float_canvas.bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN,OnKeyDown)
self.float_canvas.bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN,OnKeyUp)
.....
def OnKeyDown(evt):
    global control_pressed
    if evt.GetKeyCode() == 117 #(or whatever the code for ctrl is)
       control_pressed = True

def OnKeyUp(evt):
    global control_pressed
    if evt.GetKeyCode() == 117 #(or whatever the code for ctrl is)
       control_pressed = False
```

And then check `control_pressed` in your `wx.EVT_LEFT_UP` event handler

also in real life(tm) I suspect you would want this all in a class not globals

Comment: This was the only solution I was able to think of. Thank you for confirming that.

Comment: See http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.KeyEvent-class.html for a list of the key codes. CTRL is wx.WXK_CONTROL. You might also find this article helpful: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/29/wxpython-catching-key-and-char-events/